# Axis 2 - Steam write error

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I have a problem when I try to connect in a web service SOAP by Axi2, see the error below

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Stream write error
at      org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at     org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: the code was generate by axis2 "Wsdl2java" program

Comment: So those codes are invisible or highly confidential?

Comment: They are highly confidential, but I'm sure what the code are OK. I think is axis2 problem, because in SOAP the test was OK.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by:

1. An invalid filename. For example, /<>|?* are not allowed in the filename
2. Disk is full - if the disk is full this error can occur
3. File cannot be overwritten - the file may be locked by another process
4. If it is a network installation and there are network problems during the Developer session this could also potentially cause this error.

The workaround is to save the file to another location (e.g. locally) or with another name.
[Answer taken from here.](http://customer.argussoftware.com/s.nl/ctype.KB/it.I/id.613920/KB.3128/.f)